# Why does iTunes keep re-downloading my deleted podcast episodes?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I delete my podcast episodes from iTunes after I listen to them. Recently, I migrated from a Lion machine to a Mavericks machine (both iTunes 11), bringing my iTunes Library with me (but not my preferences file). Since then, when iTunes updates my podcast, it insists on re-downloading the episodes I've deleted (and worse, now they're marked as unplayed).

Is there a setting I need to change to stop this? It used to work fine.

Comment: Which podcast - some get reissued and iTunes don';t see them as being the same. BBV did this with In Our Time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't know why it was doing this, but I've since set iTunes to automatically delete played podcasts after 1 day, and stopped deleting them manually. That does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Go to Settings.
Tap on the 'Podcast' section.
Tap on 'Limit Episodes'.
Select how long you want your episodes to be kept.

Comment: This was fixed in iTunes after the OP posted the question and accepted his own answer.

Comment: @fsb Nothing wrong with an alternative answer, questions aren't just for OP.

Answer (score 0):

After you have verified all your settings within the app, check your phone settings --> podcast settings for "Only Download on Wi-Fi". Make sure this is checked green positive.

I recently went on a vacation in Death Valley (because there is no wifi in Death Valley) and toggled my podcast setting to NEGATIVE for "Only Download on Wi-Fi".  When I got back to civilization, I forgot to change it back to "Only Download on Wi-Fi", and this is what ate up my cellular data and battery.  It kept re-downloading stuff I already listened to and/or deleted.